# Как разбудить wi-fi

Tags: android, java

Посредством `AlarmManager` и `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` стартует `IntentService`, который должен прогуляться до сервера, пробовал делать так:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    log("------SilentService.onHandleIntent------");
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiLock = wifi.createWifiLock("SilentService");
    wifiLock.acquire();

    // wifi.reconnect(); // и так пробовал
    // wifi.setWifiEnabled(true); // и даже так )))

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            start();
            StartReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
            return;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    log("пошёл ждать интернет");
    SheduleUtility.sheduleDelayed(getApplicationContext(), 60);
    StartReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

но в лог идёт: "пошёл ждать интернет"

Answer (score 1):

В манифесте:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS 
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
```

и

```
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

у меня такая конструкция работает.

```
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);      
    try { Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if (isOnline() == false) {
        Context ctx = getBaseContext();
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Нет соединения с Интернет!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

прямо из работающего кода выдернул кусок

Comment: `android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS` - Permission is only granted to system apps      
остальные пермишены присутствуют и метод этот я уже пытал - безрезультатно.

Comment: Разница в том, что Ваш код из `Activity`, и при его выполнении аппарат пребывает в активном состоянии. У меня же `Service`, который стартует в фазе глубокого сна - всё спит, просыпается только процессор.